# Using IdentityServer to call API on behalf of a Client not User?

Tags: identityserver4

I am thinking of using IdentityServer4 for a new project.  I am new to this and have done some reading and  seen some of the demo clients in action.

Most of the clients in the samples allow login as a User and issue a token.

**Requirement**

I have multiple applications and the are for example, MVC/SPA/Mobile etc.  I wish to allow each application to be a client and call an API.

I need a setup where applications can call a protected API without a user being logged in.  So the API is protected based on scopes.

I know I can use client_credentials flow to get access_token and call my API. Which is fine for apps like the MVC as the secret will never be exposed.

I read that this flow is not recommended for mobile/SPA apps and to use Authorization Code flow, but I can't seem to get a token without it asking to login as a User.

**Question**

What other flow can I use to get only access_token without logging in the user and keeping my app secure?

Or, should I just use client_credential flow in my mobile apps and SPA's?

Comment: Why without user?

Comment: To protect endpoint so it can only be called by certain applications.